# How do I manually add Outlook to the References list?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, outlook, reference

I am trying to automate an email procedure in Outlook from Excel on Mac.

When I write a code that references `Outlook.Application`, I get an error:

> "user type could not be defined".

I believe the issue is that Outlook is not added to my "References" page under the "Tools" bar. How can I add the reference to Outlook?

```
Sub Test1()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

I expect the code to create an Outlook instance.

Answer (score 0):

The COM technology exists on Windows only. So, you will not find anything like that on Mac.

See [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) for more information.